# Error: Cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection using Serverless

Tags: node.js, mongoose, serverless-framework

I am using serverless and when I run my `serverless invoke local --function func`
I get `Error: Cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection`. Mongoose is installed @5.0.17. My func doesn't even call mongoose, but I just include it at the top with `const mongoose = require('mongoose)` and this error is thrown.

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: have you ever found a solution to this? just ran into this myself.

Comment: is there any solution for this? I've tried adding mongoose as external in my serverles yml function and running npm i --production in node_modules/mongoose but it will only run into other errors